# Google App Engine Static IP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, httprequest, ip-address, google-cloud-platform

I have a GAE project and I would like to make requests to an external server. The server needs to whitelist the IP address but GAE works with dynamic IP addresses and the list is too long. I have been looking at 2 options:

**1. Move the GAE project to Compute Engine**

My biggest concern about this is the time it would take to move the project to Compute Engine. So far we've been using App Engine for free and we would like to avoid extra costs.

**2. Use our domain to make the requests**

We could white list the IPs ourselves and receive requests from the GAE project to our domain and then make requests from the domain's static host IP itself to their server.

For this option I'd also like to know if transferring the domain to GAE has any advantage. Will the outgoing requests from GAE through the transferred domain be made through the domain's IP?

**Note:**

This is largely based on assumption, I am highly inexperienced with networking so if there's anything that could be better expressed please tell me. I tried to search online for a way to do this but couldn't get to a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Use a subdomain, then you don't have to move the whole domain to to Google App Engine.

Comment: With the subdomain will GAE make outgoing requests from the domain's IP? My biggest concern here is doing requests from App Engine through a static IP address.

Comment: I haven't checked where it will be sent from - should be easy to setup and start experimenting with.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to think about domains in this context, because you're whitelisting IPs, not domains. And it's not necessary to move the whole project, you need only move that part that makes this requests.

Just create a proxy on any server with a static IP, like micro instance on Google Compute, and do all requests through this server.

As I understand you do all request to the same external server, right? In this case it could be even simpler. You don't need to install a full featured proxy, just install an Nginx on a micro instance (with SSL and some authentication, of course) that will proxy all requests to the target server.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using RabbitMQ to send messages from Google App Engine to Compute Engine, the compute engine then forward those messages as Http requests.